# Why does MySQL ignore case consideration of query keyword's value?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database, case-sensitive

Today I'm reported a confused problem by our QA that our app's log in feature ignores case condiersation, and by debuging backend code I found the following SQL scripts run with the same results(Our database has only one user with name of 'duno'):

**`SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE username = 'duno';`**

and

**`SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE username = 'DUNO';`**

Above 2 SQL scripts run with the same user record. I just get confused about that, what special settings to MySQL need I do? or other reasons?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default mysql query is case-insensitive.

To make it case sensitive use [`BINARY` Keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html)

```
SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE BINARY username = 'duno';
```

---

Or

Instead of using the `=` operator, you use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator

```
SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE username LIKE 'duno';
```

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL does case insensitive search. You can either change your query or your table definition to make the searches case sensitive. Read more about it in MySQL documentation [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).